# Pass a selector into an an extension

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to tidy up a ViewController and would like to move the setup of a navigation item to an extension.

This is the code I am looking to move out of the ViewController:

```
private func setupNavigationItem() {
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.stashWhite(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, selector: #selector(cancelBarButtonHandler))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.stashRed(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, selector: #selector(saveBarButtonItemHandler))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

I have then created this extension.

```
extension UINavigationItem {    
    func addSavingSetup(_ cancelBarButtonHandler: Selector, _ saveBarButtonItemHandler: Selector) {
        leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.stashWhite(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, selector: cancelBarButtonHandler)
        rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.stashRed(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, selector: saveBarButtonItemHandler)
        rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

I then call it like so:

```
navigationItem.addSavingSetup(#selector(cancelBarButtonHandler(_:)), #selector(saveBarButtonItemHandler))
```

However I then get this error when tapping either the cancel or save bar button:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationItem cancelBarButtonHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105e01e80
```

Any idea how I can solve this? Not sure how else to pass in the selector.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show your selector code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting different **target**. you need to pass **target**, like below

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    func addSavingSetup(target: Any,_ cancelBarButtonHandler: Selector, _ saveBarButtonItemHandler: Selector) {
        leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.stashWhite(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: target, selector: cancelBarButtonHandler)
        rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.stashRed(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: target, selector: saveBarButtonItemHandler)
        rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that!